# Losing validation with <f:ajax>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have this form:

```
 <h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" >

        <h:outputLabel for="name"   value="Name:" />
        <h:inputText   id="name"    value="#{register.person.name}"  >  
            <f:ajax    event="blur" listener="#{register.validateName}" render="m_name" />
        </h:inputText>
        <rich:message  id="m_name"  for="name"  ajaxRendered="false"/>

        <!-- other fields -->                 

        <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{register.registerPerson}" >
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="out" />
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:outputText value="#{register.recordStatus}" id="out" />

</h:panelGrid>
```

If I try to register some person without a name and no error message is displayed. Instead, an error message appears when removing a person : `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="out" />`.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the ID of the message in the `render` as well.

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="m_name out" />
```

You can also just render the entire form if you have more than one message.

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Ajax Validation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxValidation)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but...

The attribute [`ajaxRendered`](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Common_Ajax_attributes.html#sect-Component_Reference-Rendering-ajaxRendered) of [`<rich:message>`](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages.html#sect-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages-richmessage) has a default value of `true`, which forces it to appear in AJAX responses.

You set it to `false` in Your form, and so You have to specify, which AJAX calls should re-render it.