# How to get rich:message to work with f:ajax

Tags: ajax, validation, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I've been searching and found things such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485565/losing-validation-with-fajax) link, but I am already calling the ID in the f:ajax.

I'm trying to validate the input from the first code block as an integer; this field is also looked at by a boolean check box, that allows the users to check a box, and it copy over the data to the other section of the form.  I can get the value from the first block to copy to the third, and I can get the value from the first code block to validate if I remove the f:ajax, but I cannot get the rich:message validation to work with the f:ajax call, in spite of using the ID and it being in a panel group. What am I doing wrong?

Trying to validate:

```
<h:outputLabel for="fireDrillStaffQuantity" value="Staff Quantity:"/>
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText id="fireDrillStaffQuantity" value="#     {fireDrillBean.fireDrill.fireDrillStaffQuantity}" style="width: 175px;">
         <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" bypassUpdates="#{true}"/>     
    </h:inputText>
    <rich:message for="fireDrillStaffQuantity" ajaxRendered="true"/>    
</h:panelGroup> 
<h:outputText value="*"/>
```

The boolean check box:

```
<h:outputLabel for="disasterDrillCopyTime" value="Use Fire Drill Data?"/>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{fireDrillBean.copyTimes}" id="disasterDrillCopyTime"> 
    <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="disasterDrillStartTime,disasterDrillEndTime,disasterDrillStaffQuantity,disasterDrillStaffInitials,disasterDrillSupportedQuantity,disasterDrillSupportedInitials"/>      
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputText value=""/>
```

The field that the first block gets copied to:

```
<h:outputLabel for="disasterDrillStaffQuantity" value="Staff Quantity:"/>
<h:inputText id="disasterDrillStaffQuantity" value="#{fireDrillBean.fireDrill.disasterDrillStaffQuantity}" style="width: 175px;">
    <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this"  bypassUpdates="#{true}"  render="disasterDrillStaffQuantity"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:outputText value="*"/>
```

In other parts of the form, I can get validation using an a4j:ajax call (below) but I don't know how to incorporate this into an item already using the f:ajax

```
<a4j:ajax event="blur" bypassUpdates="true" execute="@this" />
```

And just for a sanity check, here is the header of my xhtml file:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:forgeview="http://jboss.org/forge/view"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"  
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/resources/scaffold/pageTemplate.xhtml">
```

Comment: Why are you trying to rerender the input that you're validating? Edit: also, do you have to use `f:ajax`?

Comment: Honestly, this is my first web app, so I don't necessarily know why I had it there. I just removed it in my code (first code block) and the copying still works, but the validation still isn't working.  I don't necessarily need to use one technology or the other, I just need it to work.  The technical requirements are flexible, but the functional requirements are not. Do you have a suggestion to use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, ok. You're using `@ajaxRendered="true"` which means that the message has to be rendered by some ajax action.

You can either use `@render` in the `<f:ajax>` (and the message has to have an id)

```
<f:ajax … render="message" />
<rich:message id="message" … />
```

or you can use `<a4j:ajax>` instead (the attributes are the same) that will rerender the message automatically. Or you can not use the `@ajaxRendered`.

Also note that the `change` event doesn't trigger when you change the value of the input, it triggers after the input loses focus. If you want the input to validate as you're typing you should use `keyup`.

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a try and let you know if I get it working.

Comment: I went with the f:ajax and message id route and its working.  Thank you very much.